# 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Type)' cannot be converted to Type''

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

Hi i am getting the following error which i can't seem to reslove:

> Value of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential)' cannot be converted to
>   'Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.UserCredential'.

Code:

```
Using stream = New FileStream(client_Secrets, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, 
                 New YouTubeService.Scope() {YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly}, 
                 "user", CancellationToken.None, New FileDataStore(Me.[GetType]().ToString()))
End Using
```

Comment: Are you not just missing `credential = Await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync`?

Comment: @metadings If i try add the Await Keyword i get this error: 'Await' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: [The Async and Await keywords were introduced in Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156570(v=vs.110).aspx).